# Complex Linq Query with Join, count and percentage

Tags: c#, linq

I have a complex linq query I am working on.

```
var GenderStuff =
    from t1 in db.table1
    join t2 in db.table2 on t1.s_id equals t2.id
    let total = db.table2.Where(x => x.s_id == id).Count()
    where t2.s_id == id
    group t1 by new { t1.cat, total = total } into r
    select new
    {
        r.Key.cat,
        percent = (100 * (float)r.Count() / (float)r.Key.total)
    };
```

This gives me kind of what I want.  It gives me

```
[{cat:x,percent:6.66666},etc...]
```

What I want is just

```
[[category1,6.6666],[category2,33.33333]]
```

Any ideas on how I can do this with a single linq query?

Comment: LINQ is not a single thing. There are many providers: Linq2Objects, Linq2Sql, NHibernate Linq, Entity Framework Linq, OData Linq, etc. Please always specify which you're working with

Comment: I am using entity framework

Comment: does that even compile?  I wouldn't expect `r.Key` to have a `cat` property

Comment: I changed some of the names for obscurity, missed one

Comment: Are you doing JSON serialization after the query?

Comment: It's all good and fine if you don't want to post real code here, but if you do, you should make a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) and make sure that the SSCCE correctly reflects your actual problem. Otherwise, finding a solution to your problem will be more work than it should be.

Comment: and where would `category1` and `category2` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can project again into an array. I would recommend doing this after executing the query like this:

```
query.ToList().Select(item => new object[] { item.cat, item.percent }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your select statement to

```
select new [] {r.Key.cat, (100 * (float)r.Count() / (float)r.Key.total) };
```

This will only work if r.Key.cat is also a float type. Otherwise you will need to do `new object[] { ...`

**However** this is a decidedly un-c# way of doing things. An anonymous object is absolutely the appropriate thing in this situation. You seem to want a tuple, not an array - in this situation an anonymous object is actually better than a tuple as it has properly named fields. If you really really want a tuple then you would use the `Tuple` class with `select Tuple.Create(r.key.cat, ....)`